# Getting Error number 1054 on one channel entry in CP

Tags: control-panel, database-error

I've just imported a copy of a live site into my local development environment in order to make some changes, but almost immediately I've found that there is one channel entry that I cannot edit in the CP. Attempting to do so generates:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'can_access_admin' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT `can_access_admin`, `can_access_edit`, `group_id`,
>   `group_title` FROM (`exp_member_groups`) WHERE `site_id` = '1' AND
>   `can_access_content` = 'y' ORDER BY `group_id`, `group_title`
>
> Filename: models/member_model.php
>
> Line Number: 1065

Other entries in the same channel seem to be okay, and the entries of other channels seem okay also. It's just this one entry (and the entry shows up on the front end okay). I *am* able to access the entry on the 'live' site, so I did try re-exporting the live database and re-importing it into the dev environment, but the problem persists.

Can anyone shed any light on this or give me a clue about how to resolve it? (I guess I could just recreate the entry, but I'd prefer not to). I'm not much of a MySQL wrangler, I'm afraid.

EE2.9.3

Comment: At home and not at my office so can't do some research... but!! Can you track down that `column` from `exp_member_groups` and query the violating row (`SELECT * FROM database_name.exp_member_groups WHERE group_id = '1';`)? You might need to do some chaining investigation related to `group_id` access to channels.

Comment: Past any actual data fidelity issues, I'd say it is a simple environment version collision. Does your local environment match OS, PHP (and modules and config), MySQL (and modules and config), and Apache (and modules and config!!!)?

Comment: I actually have TWO local (dev) versions of this site running: one is a local mirror (in terms of EE files and DB) of the 'live' production site, whilst the other is my 'workbench' installation, which started as a direct copy of the local mirror and is the one that I am making edits to. If I log into the local mirror site then I can access the problem entry just fine. Since both the local mirror and the 'workbench' installation are running on the same install of MAMP Pro, they have the same versions/modules of Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc. So I don't *think* that it's environment collision (?).